# Problem installing Autoware with catkin

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, catkin-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had installed Autoware last week but I had to rebuild to test new nodes and I had some troubles with the grub package. So I tried updating grub and then Autoware did not work. I tried to remove the grub package to reinstall the previous version but then I deleted some necessary data from the Autoware folder. As I am working under a proxy I cant use git commands to check what is missing so I am installing again as it seems to be the easiest way to have it working again. The thing is that I dont know if I didnt installed grub package correctly or that there is a new version that causes a crash, but now the installation is not working. An error occurs when opening points2polygon.cpp.

**Required information:**

- •    Operating system and version:

  ```
     o Ubuntu 16.04
  ```
- •    Autoware installation type:

  ```
     o Installing from source. Master branch as of today.
  ```
- •    Autoware version:

  ```
     o Master branch as of today. I am still using catkin as colcon needs some dependecies from pip command and I cant  make it work with the proxy
  ```
- •    ROS distribution and version:

  ```
     o ROS Kinetic
  ```
- •    ROS Installation type

  ```
     o Build from source
  ```

**Description of the bug**

Here I attach the log of the error as it appears, the percentage sometimes changes but the error is always the same.

```
CMakeFiles/points2polygon.dir/nodes/points2polygon/points2polygon.cpp.o: (.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to pcl::search::Searchpcl::PointXYZ::getNameabi:cxx11 const’

CMakeFiles/points2polygon.dir/nodes/points2polygon/points2polygon.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Searchpcl::PointXYZ::getNameabi:cxx11 const’

CMakeFiles/points2polygon.dir/nodes/points2polygon/points2polygon.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_11PointNormalEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_11PointNormalEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Searchpcl::PointNormal::getNameabi:cxx11 const’

CMakeFiles/points2polygon.dir/nodes/points2polygon/points2polygon.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_11PointNormalEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6search6SearchINS_11PointNormalEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::search::Searchpcl::PointNormal::getNameabi:cxx11 const’

In file included from /home/ctrl2/Downloads/autoware/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/fusion_tools/packages/pixel_cloud_fusion/src/pixel_cloud_fusion.cpp:24: /home/ctrl2/Downloads/autoware/ros/src/computing/perception/detection/fusion_tools/packages/pixel_cloud_fusion/include/pixel_cloud_fusion/pixel_cloud_fusion.h:99:59: warning: private field ‘cloud_synchronizer_’ is not used [-Wunused-private-field] message_filters::Synchronizer *cloud_synchronizer_; clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

sensing/polygon/packages/points2polygon/CMakeFiles/points2polygon.dir/build.make:392: recipe for target ‘/home/ctrl2/Downloads/autoware/ros/devel/lib/points2polygon/points2polygon’ failed make[2]: * [/home/ctrl2/Downloads/autoware/ros/devel/lib/points2polygon/points2polygon] Error 1

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:19221: recipe for target ‘sensing/polygon/packages/points2polygon/CMakeFiles/points2polygon.dir/all’
```

Is it possible that when removing and installing grub I may delete some files needed in one of the dependecies as CUDA or something? I am totally lost of what is not working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320838/problem-installing-autoware-with-catkin/) by [RalLpezMartn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40816/rallpezmartn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case someone face the same problem , the solution for me was to reinstall some of the other dependencies from start. That meant CUDA, cuDNN, OpenCV, Python and ROS. After that the installation went through this part with no problems.

---

Originally posted by [RalLpezMartn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40816/rallpezmartn/) with karma: 18 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0